# Why am I getting unusual accuracies and loss on my data applying ResNet50?

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I am working on a dataset and have applied ResNet50 model. But I am getting a very unusual accuracy and loss for each of my epochs.
What am I missing that is causing the irregularities?

```
from keras.layers import Input, Lambda, Dense, Flatten, Dropout, BatchNormalization
from keras.models import Model
from keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from keras.applications.resnet50 import preprocess_input
from keras.preprocessing import image
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
from keras.models import Sequential
import numpy as np
from glob import glob
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# re-size all the images to this
IMAGE_SIZE = [224, 224]

train_path = 'Data/train'
valid_path = 'Data/test'

# add preprocessing layer to the front of resnet
resnet = ResNet50(input_shape=IMAGE_SIZE + [3], weights='imagenet', include_top=False)

# don't train existing weights
for layer in resnet.layers:
  layer.trainable = False

# useful for getting number of classes
folders = glob('Data/train/*')

# our layers - you can add more if you want
x = Flatten()(resnet.output)

# x = Dense(1000, activation='relu')(x)
prediction = Dense(len(folders), activation='softmax')(x)

# create a model object
model = Model(inputs=resnet.input, outputs=prediction)

# view the structure of the model
model.summary()

# tell the model what cost and optimization method to use
model.compile(
  loss='categorical_crossentropy',
  optimizer='adam',
  metrics=['accuracy']
)


from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255,
                               shear_range = 0.2,
                               zoom_range = 0.2,
                               horizontal_flip = True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)

training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data/train',
                                             target_size = (224, 224),
                                             batch_size = 32,
                                             class_mode = 'categorical')

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory('Data/test',
                                        target_size = (224, 224),
                                        batch_size = 32,
                                        class_mode = 'categorical')

# fit the model
r=model.fit_generator(
  generator=training_set,
  validation_data=test_set,
  epochs=25,
  steps_per_epoch=int(5144/32),
  validation_steps=int(1288/32), verbose=1
)
```

The output:

```
Epoch 1/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1891s 12s/step - loss: 1.6137 - accuracy: 0.9088 - val_loss: 10.4261 - val_accuracy: 0.0898
Epoch 2/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1766s 11s/step - loss: 1.1052 - accuracy: 0.9433 - val_loss: 6.6034 - val_accuracy: 0.6648
Epoch 3/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1761s 11s/step - loss: 1.0143 - accuracy: 0.9540 - val_loss: 11.4768 - val_accuracy: 0.0932
Epoch 4/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1758s 11s/step - loss: 0.9146 - accuracy: 0.9607 - val_loss: 5.4825 - val_accuracy: 0.6568
Epoch 5/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1785s 11s/step - loss: 1.0395 - accuracy: 0.9572 - val_loss: 9.2953 - val_accuracy: 0.6664
Epoch 6/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1816s 11s/step - loss: 1.0024 - accuracy: 0.9628 - val_loss: 6.4237 - val_accuracy: 0.6720
Epoch 7/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1838s 11s/step - loss: 1.2607 - accuracy: 0.9591 - val_loss: 9.7496 - val_accuracy: 0.6576
Epoch 8/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1761s 11s/step - loss: 1.0899 - accuracy: 0.9640 - val_loss: 2.7742 - val_accuracy: 0.6377
Epoch 9/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1762s 11s/step - loss: 1.1060 - accuracy: 0.9689 - val_loss: 11.4138 - val_accuracy: 0.6664
Epoch 10/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1762s 11s/step - loss: 0.7075 - accuracy: 0.9705 - val_loss: 8.2337 - val_accuracy: 0.6632
Epoch 11/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1769s 11s/step - loss: 1.0116 - accuracy: 0.9705 - val_loss: 8.3302 - val_accuracy: 0.6640
Epoch 12/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1765s 11s/step - loss: 0.8617 - accuracy: 0.9730 - val_loss: 4.2214 - val_accuracy: 0.6513
Epoch 13/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1763s 11s/step - loss: 0.8075 - accuracy: 0.9771 - val_loss: 25.3750 - val_accuracy: 0.0828
Epoch 14/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1763s 11s/step - loss: 1.0899 - accuracy: 0.9695 - val_loss: 37.0961 - val_accuracy: 0.0828
Epoch 15/25
160/160 [==============================] - 2073s 13s/step - loss: 0.8117 - accuracy: 0.9754 - val_loss: 32.2647 - val_accuracy: 0.1059
Epoch 16/25
160/160 [==============================] - 2169s 14s/step - loss: 0.5071 - accuracy: 0.9816 - val_loss: 14.7646 - val_accuracy: 0.0836
Epoch 17/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1818s 11s/step - loss: 0.8391 - accuracy: 0.9766 - val_loss: 14.7598 - val_accuracy: 0.0932
Epoch 18/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1796s 11s/step - loss: 0.8910 - accuracy: 0.9724 - val_loss: 5.7563 - val_accuracy: 0.6616
Epoch 19/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1795s 11s/step - loss: 0.8921 - accuracy: 0.9736 - val_loss: 16.9323 - val_accuracy: 0.0844
Epoch 20/25
160/160 [==============================] - 2061s 13s/step - loss: 0.7005 - accuracy: 0.9779 - val_loss: 22.1132 - val_accuracy: 0.0939
Epoch 21/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1807s 11s/step - loss: 0.8111 - accuracy: 0.9795 - val_loss: 35.6755 - val_accuracy: 0.0947
Epoch 22/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1917s 12s/step - loss: 0.7867 - accuracy: 0.9773 - val_loss: 31.1522 - val_accuracy: 0.0820
Epoch 23/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1975s 12s/step - loss: 0.8217 - accuracy: 0.9791 - val_loss: 34.3131 - val_accuracy: 0.1019
Epoch 24/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1842s 12s/step - loss: 0.8980 - accuracy: 0.9810 - val_loss: 12.8343 - val_accuracy: 0.1393
Epoch 25/25
160/160 [==============================] - 1828s 11s/step - loss: 0.6774 - accuracy: 0.9810 - val_loss: 18.1663 - val_accuracy: 0.0884
```

Comment: You are using all weights of resnet and they are not even trainable also its output directly connected to your prediction layer.

Comment: I don't see anything unusual here, what is unusual for you?